# What to do about many small, semantically similiar types?

Tags: java, interfaces

I'm working on a non-generic server-client-architecture in Java.
Currently, I face the issue of how to tackle `Event`-types since each event has different attributes, which don't overlap neccessarily. For now this is what I tried:

```
public interface Event {
   public void send(ServerConnection connection);
}

public static class Events {
   public class Registered implements Event {
       public final int clientId;
       public Registered(int clientId) {
          this.clientId = clientId;
       }
       public send(ServerConnection connection) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   public class Disconnected implements Event {
       public send(ServerConnection connection) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   public class Moved implements Event {
       public final int clientId;
       public final Position position;
       public Moved(int clientId, Position position) {
          this.clientId = clientId;
          this.position = position;
       }
       public send(ServerConnection connection) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   // and many more ....
}
```

However, this makes me quite unhappy, since I feel like repeating myself quite often. First, I was thinking of using an enumeration, but then I'd have unused values in there, since the attributes differ from event to event.

Comment: Welcome on SE.  This could perhaps become an interesting question. However, unfortunately, it is really unclear what you're asking and what you expect from the community.  Could you clarify ?

Comment: @Christophe I tried to clarify. Hope it's better now

Comment: This just looks like normal Java code to me … not really any avoidable repetition. Have you considered using a less verbose language? If absolutely necessary you could use annotations for code generation (→ Lombok) but that feels wrong to me.

Comment: @amon I have to use Java. It's fun. :(

Comment: @NaCL much better indeed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just looks like normal Java code to me … not really any avoidable repetition. Have you considered using a less verbose language, like Scala? Its case-classes might help.

With Java8 you get another option that may sometimes be useful. If you only need different `Event#send()` implementations but not different types, you could use a lambda instead:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Event {
   public void send(ServerConnection connection);
}

public static class Events {
   public Event registered(int clientID) {
       return connection -> { ... };
   }
   public Event disconnected() {
       return connection -> { ... };
   }
   public Event moved(int clientID, Position position) {
       return connection -> { ... };
   }
   // and many more ....
}
```

In most scenarios that is sufficient, but you do lose a bit debuggability and the ability to check `if (ev instanceof Events.Moved)` etc.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of scala case classes. if OP really wanted they could even write the messages in scala and then do the rest in java.